# Samba: Second User permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, samba

i set up Samba on my home server to share a directory. I can easily access the network drives of samba with my first user (which is also my main user on the server). The second can't access any of these drives at all. I already tried to change the ownership of these directories, to delete and create a new user, change passwords, etc.

My smb.conf:

```
[global]

        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = never
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/16
        hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
        security = user

[share]
        comment = Test
        path = /var/www/extern_drive/samba/share
        read only = no
        guest ok = no
        valid users = first second
        force create mode = 0755
        force group = smbgroup

[second]
        path = /var/www/extern_drive/samba/second
        read only = no
        guest ok = no
        valid users = second
        force create mode = 0700
        force group = second
```

My log.smbd

```
[2023/12/15 17:31:28.892725,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/var/www/extern_drive/samba/second) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=1001, gid=1001, 1 groups: 1001
[2023/12/15 17:31:28.896260,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/var/www/extern_drive/samba/second) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=1001, gid=1001, 1 groups: 1001
[2023/12/15 17:31:30.645442,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/var/www/extern_drive/samba/second) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=1001, gid=1001, 1 groups: 1001
```

EDIT:

I created the second user with the command:
`$ sudo useradd -d /home/second -s /sbin/nologin second`

After that I added the user to samba with `smbpasswd -a second`